# Find index locations of a specified letter in a string

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, string

My apologies if I didn't explain it clear the first time. I have edited my explanation further in bold below.

In the program below user enters a word and then enters a letter which the user would like to replace with any character. For instance, user enter's a word "Hello" and the replacement letter is "l" with "$". So "Hello" will become "He$$o". **First, the goal is to find the location of "l" (example - 2,3) and then replace the element in that specific location.**

I started by finding the location of "l" and storing it in a findIndex array. Every time I run the program I get "22222" stored in findIndex[] array. At this point, I am not even sure if I am even applying the right logic. Any advice will be appreciated! Please don't use LINQ.

```
public static void RemoveSpecifiedCharacters()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nWrite a word/sentence: ");
        string myString = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write("Type the character you would like to replace: ");
        string myCharacter = Console.ReadLine();
        int[] findIndex = new int[myString.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < myString.Length; i++)
        {

            findIndex[i] = myString.IndexOf(myCharacter, 0);

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < findIndex.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(findIndex[i]);
        }           
    }
```

Comment: [String.Replace()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: IS this your aim? `user enter's a word "Hello" and the replacement letter is "l" with "$". So "Hello" will become "He$$o".` then try `String.Replace()`

Comment: The second parameter of the IndexOf method is the starting index for the search - you are always starting at index 0, so it will always find the "l" at the third character (index=2). It is not clear what you are actually trying to do in your first loop. Are you trying to create an array of positions the character appears? If that is what you want then the example here may help you : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5xkyx09y(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably what you want :

```
public static void RemoveSpecifiedCharacters()
{
    Console.WriteLine("\nWrite a word/sentence: ");
    string myString = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.Write("Type the character you would like to replace: ");
    string myCharacter = Console.ReadLine();
    List<int> findIndex = new List<int>();

    int offs = 0;
    while (offs < myString.Length)
    {
      offs = myString.IndexOf(myCharacter, offs);;
      if (offs == -1)
        break;
      findIndex.Add(offs);
      offs++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < findIndex.Count; i++)
    {
        Console.Write(findIndex[i]);
    }           
}
```

Set an initial offset to the start of the string, try to find index of required character if not found exit, otherwise store the location & increment the offset so the next loop starts after the found position. Then keep looping.

As you do not know how many characters will be found, then a list is better than an array to store the results. It can always be converted to an array with .ToArray() afterwards.

Comment: This is great. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Below should serve the purpose :

```
var str = "Hello";
var replaced = str.Replace('l', '$');
```

Comment: The title of the question is "Find index locations of a specified letter in a string". Your code will do the replacement, but not answer the question.

Comment: Probably you need to refine your question : "In the program below user enters a word and then enters a letter which the user would like to replace with any character. **For instance, user enter's a word "Hello" and the replacement letter is "l" with "$". So "Hello" will become "He$$o"**

Comment: As the OP's code makes no attempt to replace the letter, maybe the question is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Even though it's easier to use `String.Replace`, I just want to give you an explanation why you are getting [2,2,2,2,2] array.

Firstly, `IndexOf` method returns index of character's first occurence, starting from 0.

Secondly, you are using method overload `IndexOf(myCharacter, 0)` which "says" that character search should be done always from the start of the string.

To circumvent the issue, you should use `IndexOf(myCharacter, i, 1)` instead to set the search to start from i-th character, not the start of string.

Comment: You would need to modify the loop - otherwise the output is 2 2 2 3 -1

Comment: I updated the answer, so basically IndexOf will check only the one character

Comment: And now the result is -1 -1 2 3 -1 - pretty sure OP doesn't want that either.

Comment: We need to wait for OP's response :)

Comment: I see our wait is over

Comment: Your response has been helpful. Can you please further explain why the result is -1 for the location that is not an "l"

Comment: @Amit When IndexOf doesn't find specified character it returns -1

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Darjan!

Answer (score 0):

I guess a simple solution would be to split the string into a character array and then do the comparison? 
For example something like:

```
        Console.WriteLine("\nWrite a word/sentence: ");
        char[] myString = Console.ReadLine().ToCharArray();

        Console.Write("Type the character you would like to replace: ");
        char myCharacter = Console.ReadLine().ToCharArray()[0];
        int[] findIndex = new int[myString.Length];
        int indexCount = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < myString.Length; i++)
        {
            if (myString[i] == myCharacter)
                findIndex[indexCount++] = i;

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < indexCount; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(findIndex[i]);
        }
```

Comment: it would print the index 0 as intended? and it won't print any indices (not even a 0) in case of no search match.

Comment: `Nothing` See the last loop.

Comment: Sorry, missed that.